# Verifying the integrity of PyPI Python packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, security, pypi

Recently there came some news about some **Malicious Libraries** that were uploaded into Python Package Index (PyPI), see:

1. [Malicious libraries on PyPI](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/ten-malicious-libraries-found-on-pypi-python-package-index/)
2. [Malicious modules found into official Python repository](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/09/devs-unknowingly-use-malicious-modules-put-into-official-python-repository/?comments=1) (this link contains the list of malicious packages)
3. [Developers using malicious Python Modules](https://developers.slashdot.org/story/17/09/16/2030229/pythons-official-repository-included-10-malicious-typo-squatting-modules)

I am not trying to forward these news but I am trying to prevent myself and other teammates to identify if a package from PyPI has not been altered by an external party.

Questions:

1. What security check should I use once I have downloaded a package from PyPI? MD5 or any extra step?
2. Is MD5 signature enough to verify the integrity of Python Packages?

Comment: Typosquatting has nothing to do with hash. You have to verify if it's the upstream package you're using.

Comment: Another question: Once I download a package and review that it has not any typosquatting, should MD5 signature be enough to check the integrity of this package?

Comment: pip should verify the MD5 signature, and it's not easy (if possible) to collide it. EDIT: the new PyPI frontend (pypi.io) has migrated to SHA256.

Comment: But `pip` does not support cryptographic signatures, so this way is not possible.

Comment: "Another question: Once I download a package and review that it has not any typosquatting, should MD5 signature be enough to check the integrity of this package?" No, MD5 is not a signature; it's a hash. And it's an insecure hash at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the article describes the danger of **typosquatting**, which is caused by developers blindly installing package by name without checking if it's the correct upstream package. You can avoid this by going to the author's GitHub repository and copy the install instructions correctly.

Aside from that, packages can be tampered but unlikely. As the PyPI files are transferred through HTTPS, it doesn't make much sense to fetch a hash from server and verify it. (If the author's account or the PyPI server is hacked, hash doesn't prevent you from installing malicious packages.)

If you need extra security measure against server compromise, use pinned version/hashes. See the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode) for details.

Answer (score 3):

First, your concern of obtaining malicious files when downloading from `PyPI` using `pip` is valid. In fact as of 2020, [`pip` has no way to cryptographically validate the authenticity and integrity](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/234098/213165) of the software it downloads (but it has been a TODO item since 2013)

Second, `md5` can verify the integrity of a file, but it can't do so securely. Nor is checking the integrity sufficient. To *securely* verify that a file downloaded from `pip` is the file you expect, you have to:

1. Authenticate the the file by confirming that it was in-fact produced by the publisher (using a cryptographic signature) and
2. Verify the integrity of the file after download

Though `pip` doesn't have built-in support for this, you can do it manually by downloading the file you want and its detached signature file from `PyPI` manually, followed by checking the signature using `gpg`.

For example, the `borgbackup` project can be viewed here on PyPI's website:

- https://pypi.org/project/borgbackup/

Clicking the "Download Files" button gives you an option to download the lastest tarball at the following URL:

- https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz

Alternatively, you can also get this URL using cURL against the [PyPI "simple" API](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/234098/213165)

```
user@disp5066:~$ curl -s https://pypi.org/simple/borgbackup/ | grep -i borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz
    <a href="https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz#sha256=164a8666a61071ce2fa6c60627c7646f12e3a8e74cd38f046be72f5ea91b3821">borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz</a><br/>
user@disp5066:~$
```

To get the signature of this file, simply append `.asc` to the URL:

```
user@disp5066:~$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc
--2020-07-02 07:51:12--  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/68/27d96a12f54894223ad6676ce4d215ad61771e3e723580f3ee6e609e17b7/borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc
Resolving files.pythonhosted.org (files.pythonhosted.org)... 151.101.37.63, 2a04:4e42:9::319
Connecting to files.pythonhosted.org (files.pythonhosted.org)|151.101.37.63|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 862 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc’

borgbackup-1.1.13.t 100%[===================>]     862  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2020-07-02 07:51:14 (37.2 MB/s) - ‘borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc’ saved [862/862]

user@disp5066:~$ cat borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc 
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=F4gj
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
user@disp5066:~$
```

Pip also has no way to mark the gpg key used for signing a package as the "official" key, so you have to hope that the author has published their key in a few distinct domains so you can fetch it out-of-band a few ways to confirm it's correct then import it and trust it. After that, you can use `gpg` to verify the signature of the file downloaded from PyPI.

```
gpg --verify borgbackup-1.1.13.tar.gz.asc
```

See also:

1. https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/issues/4213
2. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232855/does-pythons-pip-provide-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation